# Is there a way to pass a named argument?

Tags: python, parameters

Here's my code:

```
def update_tags_with_value(tags, many_to_many_class):
    if tags:
        many_to_many_class.objects.filter(
            personne=self.instance,

            date_v_fin=None
        ).update(date_v_fin=django_datetime.now())
        for idx_tag_with_value in tags:
            pl = many_to_many_class.objects.create(
                personne=self.instance,
                langue=TagWithValue.objects.get(
                    pk=idx_tag_with_value
                )
            )
            pl.save()

update_tags_with_value(self.cleaned_data.get('known_languages'),
                       PersonneLangue)
update_tags_with_value(self.cleaned_data.get('types_permis'),
                       PersonneTypesPermis)
```

So I found out I can easily pass a class as a parameter. But the last problem is about the named argument. If you watch my code, I do a `langue=TagWithValue..[blabla]`. The problem is that it's a "named" parameter, and I'd like to be able to pass it like that:

```
update_tags_with_value(self.cleaned_data.get('known_languages'),
                       PersonneLangue, 'langue')
update_tags_with_value(self.cleaned_data.get('types_permis'),
                       PersonneTypesPermis, 'permis')
```

And then to call it somehow like that (it doesn't work *yet*):

```
    def update_tags_with_value(tags, many_to_many_class, champ):
        if tags:
            many_to_many_class.objects.filter(
                personne=self.instance,

                date_v_fin=None
            ).update(date_v_fin=django_datetime.now())
            for idx_tag_with_value in tags:
                pl = many_to_many_class.objects.create(
                    personne=self.instance,
                    champ=TagWithValue.objects.get(
                        pk=idx_tag_with_value
                    )
                )
                pl.save()
```

For now I get this error:

```
'champ' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

To be more precise, I need to call `many_to_many_class.objects.create()` one time with `known_languages=blabla` and another time with `types_permis=blabla` which, in other words, should call once `many_to_many_class.objects.create(known_languages=blabla)` and `many_to_many_class.objects.create(types_permis=blabla)` and I would like to know if there's a way to precise *only the name of the parameter*, **not** `blabla`

How to solve this?

Comment: I don't 100% understand what you want, but [named argument unpacking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters) may be useful to you. You can create a dictionary and pass it to a function as if it was a collection of keyword args.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my working solution, I don't know if it's the best "pythonic" way but it works like a charm:

```
def update_tags_with_value(tags, many_to_many_class, champ):
    if tags:
        many_to_many_class.objects.filter(
            personne=self.instance,
            date_v_fin=None
        ).update(date_v_fin=django_datetime.now())
        for idx_tag_with_value in tags:
            args = {
                'personne': self.instance,
                champ: TagWithValue.objects.get(
                    pk=idx_tag_with_value
                )}
            pl = many_to_many_class.objects.create(**args)
            pl.save()

update_tags_with_value(self.cleaned_data.get('known_languages'),
                       PersonneLangue, 'langue')
update_tags_with_value(self.cleaned_data.get('types_permis'),
                       PersonneTypePermis, 'type_permis')
update_tags_with_value(self.cleaned_data.get('diplomes'),
                       PersonneDiplome, 'diplome')
update_tags_with_value(self.cleaned_data.get('centres_dinteret'),
                       PersonneCentreDInteret, 'centre_dinteret')
update_tags_with_value(self.cleaned_data.get('hobbies'),
                       PersonneHobby, 'hobby')
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like normal keyword unpacking would work . . .

```
kwargs = {champ: TagWithValue.objects.get(
                     pk=idx_tag_with_value)}
pl = many_to_many_class.objects.create(
                    personne=self.instance,
                    **kwargs)
```

Of course, now `champ` *might* not be the best name for the function parameter, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: My problem is that, strictly speaking, I need to call `many_to_many_class.objects.create()` one time with `known_languages=blabla` and another time with `types_permis=blabla` which, in other words, should call once `many_to_many_class.objects.create(known_languages=blabla)` and `many_to_many_class.objects.create(types_permis=blabla)` and I would like to know if there's a way to precise *only the name of the parameter*, **not** `blabla`